# How to read text from a url and parse it in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In php I am using curl but being new to Ruby and Rails, I am little lost about the best way to do this,

So I have http://example.com/api?=topmovies&ratings which returns list of 10 movies with their ratings. Unfortunately it is not in json/xml but just text so I was wondering,

1. How to read/retrieve the text from url in rails
2. How to parse/put the data in variables (it has 2 columns and 10 rows)

Thanks

Comment: you should read on nokogiri if you want to do this. http://nokogiri.org/

Comment: +1 for lulz, nokogiri on xml: "XML is like violence - if it doesn’t solve your problems, you are not using enough of it."

Answer (score 1):

You could use `curl` with ruby too, but the preferred way to interact with websites is with the `mechanize` gem. Take a look at the [mechanize examples page](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/EXAMPLES_rdoc.html) to see how to get the page from a website and parse through the content.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RestClient gem](https://github.com/archiloque/rest-client) to get content of another website.